# How to convert structure vertical to horizontal with Pandas

Tags: pandas

I would like to change structure of following Dataframe to next .

```
| id | name | country | sort |
| 1 | Foo | USA | 1 |
| 1 | Foo | Japan | 2 |
| 1 | Foo | China | 3 |
| 2 | Bar | USA | 1 |
| 2 | Bar | UK | 3 |
| 2 | Bar | France | 4 |
| 3 | Zap | Japan | 2 |
| 3 | Zap | UK | 3 |
| 3 | Zap | Russia | 5 |
```

It is convert vertical to horizontal.

```
| id | name | country01 | country02 | country03 |
| 1 | Foo | USA | Japan | China |
| 2 | Bar | USA | UK | France |
| 3 | Zap | Japan | UK | Russia |
```

I was trying to use pd.pivot_table. 
However it does not seem to be fit for this process.

Are there any idea?

Extra Info

```
| id | name | country01 | sort01 | country02 | sort02 | country03 | sort03 |
| 1 | Foo | USA | 1 | Japan | 2 | China | 3 |
| 2 | Bar | USA | 1| UK | 3 | France | 4 |
| 3 | Zap | Japan | 2 | UK | 3 | Russia | 5 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and then reshape by  [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['id','name', 
                    df.groupby(['id','name']).cumcount().add(1)])['country']
        .unstack()
        .add_prefix('country')
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
   id name country1 country2 country3
0   1  Foo      USA    Japan    China
1   2  Bar      USA       UK   France
2   3  Zap    Japan       UK   Russia
```

EDIT: You can create MultiIndex, sorting by second levl and flatten in list comprehension:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['id','name', 
                    df.groupby(['id','name']).cumcount().add(1)])
        .unstack()
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df1.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   id name country1  sort1 country2  sort2 country3  sort3
0   1  Foo      USA      1    Japan      2    China      3
1   2  Bar      USA      1       UK      3   France      4
2   3  Zap    Japan      2       UK      3   Russia      5
```

Comment: What if I want to put sort column after each country’s columns as well?

Comment: @tajihiro - Can you explain more?

Comment: I added structure as Extra Info the last.