# How to convert horizontal dataframe structure to vertical with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a problem similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845916/how-to-convert-structure-vertical-to-horizontal-with-pandas) but in reverse. I need an idea how to write the dataframe vertically using the first column `id` as key.

So to start, an example of my input dataframe looks like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'tag': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'tag2': ['f','g','h','i','j'], 'tag3': ['k','l','m','','']})
>>> df
   id tag tag2 tag3
0   1   a    f    k
1   2   b    g    l
2   3   c    h    m
3   4   d    i
4   5   e    j
```

My desired output should be like this:

```
>>> df
    id tag
0    1   a
1    1   f
2    1   k
3    2   b
4    2   g
5    2   l
6    3   c
7    3   h
8    3   m
9    4   d
10   4   i
11   5   e
12   5   j
```

It looks like I have to use the entries of the `id` column as a key to my dictionary right? Like a `default_dict(list)`:

```
{1:['a','k','l'], 2:['b','g','l'], 3:['c','h','m'], 4:['d','i'], 5:['e','j']}
```

I just have trouble placing all column values per row into the dictionary as list, I already know how to make a dictionary if using two(2) columns only like :

`some_dict = dict(zip(df['col1'],df['col2']))`

But not as list as above.

Also, if there's a pandas solution to this that would be most ideal.

Since if I figure out how to create the dictionary with key values = list, I plan to loop it to change the format and create the desired DataFrame, and looping is not always advisable especially when working with large DataFrames.

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers!

### Edit

Just figured out how to create a dictionary with list as values:

```
>>> x = df.set_index('id').T.to_dict('list')
>>> x
{1: ['a', 'f', 'k'], 2: ['b', 'g', 'l'], 3: ['c', 'h', 'm'], 4: ['d', 'i', ''], 5: ['e', 'j', '']}
```

So my problem now is how to utilize this dictionary to create a new dataframe as the desired output.

Thanks.

Comment: Try something like `df.mask(df.eq('')).set_index('id').stack()`

Comment: [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) is meant for exactly this. Just need to rename `tag` to `tag0`

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response, I will try to use the ones  you suggested here.

Comment: Hello, an update @user3483203 the solution worked, but i need the `ids` to be repeated in the first column. The result of your solution is somewhat like a groupby() result? But it works, thank you. 

@anky_91 your solution is the one I exactly look for. Thank you, please post your answer so I can vote up.

Comment: @anky_91: my solution is really similar to yours. To be clear, I never see yours before I come up with mine :)

Comment: On a train and can't write an answer. Can anyone kindly test df.set_index('id').apply(list,axis=1).explode()

Comment: @MarkWang there's an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: @Joe explode is introduced in 0.25

Comment: I see. My pandas must be of older version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.replace('', np.nan).set_index('id').stack().reset_index(name='tag').drop('level_1',1)

Out[100]:
    id tag
0    1   a
1    1   f
2    1   k
3    2   b
4    2   g
5    2   l
6    3   c
7    3   h
8    3   m
9    4   d
10   4   i
11   5   e
12   5   j
```

Comment: Thanks. Kindly upvote my question if it is not too much to ask, cheers!

Comment: @Joe: I did. The current upvoting '+1' on this question is mine :)

Answer (score 3):

```
(df.melt(id_vars=["id"],value_vars =["tag",'tag2','tag3'],value_name="tag")
 .drop('variable',axis=1)
 .replace('', np.nan,)
 .dropna()
 .sort_values('id')
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the solution worked, I just have to add `df.reset_index(inplace  = True, drop = True)`